Processing netcdf file using python script on linux cluster - no output but no error
import os
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr

# Load environment variables (if needed)
os.system("source ~/.bashrc")

# Define the input directory and base output directory
input_dir = '/users/ij/All_Runs/1_1/80/'
base_output_dir = '/users/ij/'

# Create a new output directory for this run
output_dir = os.path.join(base_output_dir, 'Processed_Output')
os.makedirs(output_dir, exist_ok=True)

print(f"Input Directory: {input_dir}")
print(f"Output Directory: {output_dir}")

# List of timeslices to extract
timeslices = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]

# Check if the input directory exists
if not os.path.isdir(input_dir):
    print(f"Input directory does not exist: {input_dir}")
else:
    print(f"Input directory exists: {input_dir}")

# List files in the input directory
files = os.listdir(input_dir)
print(f"Files in input directory: {files}")

# Loop through all .nc files in the input directory
for file_name in files:
    if file_name.endswith('.nc'):
        try:
            # Load NetCDF dataset using xarray
            file_path = os.path.join(input_dir, file_name)
            print(f"Processing file: {file_path}")
            data = xr.open_dataset(file_path)
            
            # Select specific variables
            variables = ['Z1', 'Z2', 'Z3', 'Z4', 'density']
            df = data[variables]

            # Sum the Z1, Z2, Z3, and Z4 variables and add as a new variable 'Z_Total'
            df['Z_Total'] = df['Z1'] + df['Z2'] + df['Z3'] + df['Z4']

            # Add the new variable 'Conc' calculated as Z_Total * density
            df['Conc'] = df['Z_Total'] * df['density']

            # Loop through each timeslice and process
            for timeslice in timeslices:
                print(f"Processing timeslice: {timeslice}")

                # Select the new variables 'Z_Total', 'density', and 'Conc'
                df_summed = df[['Z_Total', 'density', 'Conc']]

                # Select the specific timeslice (ensure 'zt' is a valid dimension in your dataset)
                timeslice_summed = df_summed.sel(zt=timeslice, method='nearest')

                # Calculate the conc_ppm_m variable
                timeslice_summed['conc_ppm_m'] = timeslice_summed['Conc'] * 1000000

                # Convert the timeslice to a DataFrame
                df_timeslice_summed = timeslice_summed.to_dataframe()

                # Define the output CSV file path
                output_csv_path = os.path.join(output_dir, f"{file_name}_zt{timeslice}_ZTotal_Conc.csv")

                # Save the DataFrame to a CSV file
                df_timeslice_summed.to_csv(output_csv_path)

                print(f"Data from {file_name} for zt={timeslice} saved to {output_csv_path}")

        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Failed to process file {file_name}: {e}")

Hi,
I am processing some NetCDF files generated from plume simulation with .nc format. In this scripts, I am generating 2D slices from the 3D simulation output. This script works fine in my Mac laptop and generates the output. When I run this script in the Linux cluster, I runs with no error and no output. This is what it generates as output in the Linux cluster:
(dp) user@cluster: All_Runs >python Timeslice_Automated.py
Input Directory: /users/ij/All_Runs/1_1/80/
Output Directory: /users/ij/Processed_Output
Input directory exists: /users/ij/All_Runs/1_1/80/
Files in input directory: ['Processed_Output']
(dp) user@cluster:~/users/ij/Processed_Output> ls -l
total 0
